# Regular Expression Inception (a match within a match)

Tags: regex, perl, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to create a regular expression that captures a named group and then looks within that named group to check if it contains certain qualities.

For example. I have a regular expression that matches a code block and I can use it to match and capture code blocks:

**test.pl:**

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $text = <<'END_TEXT';

block {
    // random stuff
}

block {
    dog
}

END_TEXT

my $code_block_rx = qr{(?(DEFINE)
(?<code_block>
    block\h\{ (?: [^{}]++ | (?&code_block) )*+ \}
)
)}xms;

while ($text =~ m/(?<match>(?&code_block))$code_block_rx/g) {
    print $+{match}."\n";
}
```

This code will print both code blocks. But what if I only want to capture code blocks that contain the word "dog"?

Is there a way (in a single regular expression) to capture a code block, and then if that is found, look within the code block for the word "dog"?

I've tried modifying the regex to use a look ahead assertion, but it just causes the whole thing to fail: `/(?<match>(?=dog)(?&code_block))$code_block_rx/g`

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not possible as far as I'm aware. You could always add a new definition though: `(?<code_block_dog>block\h\{(?=[^{}]*dog[^{}]*)(?:[^{}]++|(?&code_block))*+\})`

Comment: I guess I'm misunderstanding something. Why can't you just match something like `/block \{\s*dog\s*\}/`? Put parentheses around whichever part you want to capture.

Comment: That's not what "inception" means. You want "recursion".

Comment: You tried to match dog at the position where the match starts.

Comment: @melpomene, Regex recursion is an entirely different subject. Recursion involves a regex that calls itself. A "regex within a regex" is not the same as recursion. The term "inception" as it is used in this question referring to its use in the movie "Inception" where the characters fall asleep and enter a dream world in which they fall asleep again to enter a dream within a dream... and then a dream within a dream within a dream... etc...

Comment: @tjwrona1992 That's not what the movie title is about. "Inception" refers to the planting of an idea. What you're describing is recursion ("X within an X").

Comment: @melpomene What I am describing is not recursion. Recursion would be "X" within "X". I want "Y" within "X" which cannot be done with recursion. And yes that may be what the word inception really means, but since that movie it has at least culturally adopted a second meaning. Even if it isn't technically proper use of the word it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to match `dog` at the position where the match starts.

Instead, you can check if it's in the block you matched.

```
while ($text =~ /(
    \b block \h*+ ( (?&code_block) )

    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<code_block>      \{ (?&code_block_body) \}        )
        (?<code_block_body> (?: [^{}]++ | (?&code_block) )*+ )
    )
)/xg) {
    my $block_stmt       = $1;
    my $block_stmt_block = $2;
    if ($block_stmt_block =~ /\b dog \b/x) {
         say $block_stmt;
    }
}
```

It can be done in a single pattern by using `(?(?{!( assertion() )})(*FAIL))` to match against something you already captured.

```
while ($text =~ m{(
    \b block \h*+
    # A code_block that contains the word 'dog'.
    ( (?&code_block) ) (?(?{!( "$^N" =~ /\b dog \b/x )})(*FAIL))

    (?(DEFINE)
        (?<code_block>      \{ (?&code_block_body) \}        )
        (?<code_block_body> (?: [^{}]++ | (?&code_block) )*+ )
    )
)}xg) {
    say $1;
}
```

Comment: I know I can do it with two separate regular expressions and a Perl `if` statement, but I am wondering if the Regular Expression language is capable of doing this with a single expression.

Comment: The issue is `(?&code_block)` is reused other places so I can't modify it's definition. I want to match a generic `(?&code_block)` and then if that matches look inside of what I just matched.

Comment: Not sure, it wasn't me. Not sure why I got a downvote either... apparently people don't know good content when they see it... I'll upvote your answer because it didn't deserve a downvote.

Comment: I think your answer is doing what I want, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the `(*FAIL)` block works.

Comment: `(*FAIL)` never matches. It's like `(?!)` or `(?:\z.)`. It's being used inside of `(?(?{ condition() })THEN_PATTERN|ELSE_PATTERN)`

Comment: If i copy and paste your exact regex it works, but when I try to adapt my own regex `$text =~ m/((?&code_block))(?(?{!( "$^N" =~ /\b dog \b/x )})(*FAIL))$code_block_rx/xg` it doesn't seem to work. I get an error saying "Sequence (?{...}) not terminated with ')'"

Comment: You actually have `$text =~ m/((?&code_block))(?(?{!( "$^N" =~ /`

Comment: Ohhhhhhh that makes sense! Thanks!

Comment: I made the same mistake earlier :)